# Outlook 2007 "Mark as Not Junk" Dialog Confusion

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, spam-prevention

Outlook 2007's "Not Junk" button opens the "Mark as Not Junk" dialog. The dialog works correctly if I keep the "Always trust e-mail from <email address>" option checked. That is, the message is removed from the Junk folder and returns to the Inbox.

However, if I uncheck the "Always trust" box, pressing OK dismisses the dialog, but nothing else happens. Why not?

According to Outlook help, "When you mark a message as not junk, you are given the option of adding the sender or the mailing list name to your Safe Senders List or Safe Recipients List." That sure makes it sound like this is just an option, and not necessary for the core functionality of the action.

I really don't want to trust a (possibly forged) From: address, but I do want my mail back in the Inbox.  I could manually drag it, but I'm assuming that marking a message as not junk also trains some kind of bayesian filter. Am I mistaken?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think dragging it back to the inbox does is exactly the same as marking as not junk. I could be wrong, which is why I'm not posting an answer.

Comment: Interesting.  I never noticed that because I always want to add the sender to the 'always trusted' list.  But I can understand why someone might want to mark one particular message as not junk without necessarily adding the sender or the recipient to the trusted list.  And since the distinguishing factor is whether or not the message is in the junk folder, then it makes sense when marking a message as 'not junk' to move it back to the inbox.  Perhaps "Mark as not junk" is not the right name for the feature. Or the junk filter is just doing its job and junking the message again immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a dialog confusion because you can uncheck the "Always trust e-mail from " option and check the "Always trust e-mail sent to the following addresses" - this will add the checked email addresses to the Safe Recipients (all emails sent to addresses or domain names on your Safe Recipient List will never be treated as junk email).

If no option is checked then nothing happens - you need to check at least one option to move it automatically back in your Inbox.

Comment: What are you talking about? There's only one check box in that dialog, "Always trust e-mail from ..." Un-checking that option makes the dialog do nothing, even though the text *before* the check box says the "message will be moved back into the Inbox Folder." There is no second check box, and even if there were, I wouldn't want to *always* trust anything based solely on the supposed source or destination.